# How to create a list of due dates which are dynamically added base from approved date in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am doing a credit collection app which offer loans to the borrowers. I've been stock in this for so many days now because I can't think of a better way to do it.

SO basically I want to achieve is to have a list of due dates which I will display in the borrower dashboard. for example, the borrower applied for a 2 months loan duration and bi-monthly payment scheme and let say the admin approve it today. So what I want is base from the date today, 12-10-2021 the system will generate 4 due dates(12-25-2021, 12-8-2021, 1-23-2022 and 02-7-2022) and will save them to a separate due dates table.

With regards to the payments, I can analyze the part where the system can check if the payment is done on or before the first due date but how can I tell to the system that the payment is advance payment for the next 3 due date?

what I only have right now is this

```
$date_approval = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($loan_application->date_approval));
$scheme_numdays = $loan_application->scheme->num_days;

$days = (intdiv($date_approval->diff(Carbon::now())->days , $scheme_numdays) + 1) * $scheme_numdays

$due_date = $date_approval->addDays($days)->format('M d Y');
```

Which can identify the first due date.

Can you help to point to any resources out there than will help me achieve my objective? I am hoping I was able to describe the question and my objective clearly. Any suggestions will be very much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!

**RESPONSE FOR @GRANT**

I am following your code

```
$date_approval = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($loanapplication->date_approval));
$scheme_numdays = $loanapplication->scheme->num_days;

$days = (intdiv($date_approval->diff(Carbon::now())->days , $scheme_numdays) + 1) * $scheme_numdays;

$due_date = $date_approval->addDays($days)->format('Y-m-d');
$due_date_plus = $date_approval->addDays(60)->format('Y-m-d');

# Carbon Period usage:
$result = CarbonPeriod::create($due_date, $scheme_numdays.' days', $due_date_plus);
```

I replace the '# days' in the $result with $scheme_numdays so which contains the number of days.

Then I display it like this,

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    {{$date_approval}}<br/>
    {{$loanapplication->date_approval}}<br/>
    @foreach ($result as $dt)
        {{$dt->format("M d Y")}} <br/>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

the result is

```
2022-02-27 00:00:00
2021-12-14
Dec 29 2021
Jan 13 2022
Jan 28 2022
Feb 12 2022
Feb 27 2022
```

**Question:**

why **{{$date_approval}}** (2022-02-27 00:00:00) and **{{$loanapplication->date_approval}}** (2021-12-14) gave different result? The date 2021-12-14 is what I have in my database.

My second question is why the result is five instead of 4 only?

The Data I'm displaying is, the loan duration is 60 days and the payment scheme is on every 15 days or fortnightly.

Comment: because `$date_approval` is instance of `Carbon`, `date_approval` is string, you can tell laravel which is date `protected $dates = ['due_date', 'date_approval',...];`

Comment: thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CarbonPeriod would be perfect for this particular scenario. Have you tried the following:

```php
$date_approval = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($loan_application->date_approval));
$scheme_numdays = $loan_application->scheme->num_days;

$days = (intdiv($date_approval->diff(Carbon::now())->days , $scheme_numdays) + 1) * $scheme_numdays

$due_date = $date_approval->addDays($days)->format('Y-m-d');
$due_date_plus = $date_approval->addMonths(8)->format('Y-m-d');

# Carbon Period usage:
$result = CarbonPeriod::create($due_date, '2 months', $due_date_plus);
  
foreach ($result as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("M d Y");
}
```

You may need to namespace it:

```php
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
```

Edited answer for followup questions:

```php
<div class="col-md-6">
    {{ $date_approval->format('M d Y') }}<br/>
    {{ $loanapplication->date_approval->format('M d Y') }}<br/>
    @foreach ($result as $dt)
        @if($loop->index > 3)
            @break
        @endif
        {{ $dt->format('M d Y') }}<br />
    @endforeach
</div>
```

An alternative is date casting when getting dates from models.
(in loan application model):

```
protected $casts = [
    'date_approval' => 'datetime:M d Y',
];
```

Comment: Thanks Grant! yes it seems to work because it gave 4 result for a 60 day loan duration and bi-monthly or 15 days payment scheme. but the dates are not correct. for example the date approval is 12-14-2021. The results given are, Dec 29 2021, Mar 01 2022, May 01 2022 and Jul 01 2022 which supposedly 12-14-2021 + 15 days then another 15 days so on.

Comment: @Lito you mean you need fortnightly? -- confused because of the term bi-monthly - which now I know can mean twice a month or every two months. For fortnightly you just change `addMonths(8)` to `addDays(60)` and then inside of the `CarbonPeriod` call change `2 months` to `15 days`. That should cut it?

Comment: Did that work for you mate? @Lito

Comment: Hi Grant i think we're almost there I just have some further question. Please check out my updated question. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Lito I adjusted my answer for your followup questions

Comment: thanks! i just awarded to you the bounty. I just replace the @if($loop->index > 3) with @if($loop->index === $loopIndex). where the  $loopIndex = $loanapplication->loanDuration->num_days / $scheme_numdays; Thanks for your help @grant!